Specific Question about Deriving the Fisher Information for a Complex Multivariate Normal Distribution
I am starting with the following form for the likelihood function for a complex multivariate normal distribution for data with dimension $d$ and mean $\boldsymbol \mu$:
$$
p(\mathbf x|\boldsymbol \theta)=\frac{1}{\pi^d |\boldsymbol\Sigma|}\exp\left[-\frac{1}{2} (\mathbf x-\boldsymbol \mu)^{\mathrm H} \boldsymbol\Sigma^{-1} (\mathbf x-\boldsymbol \mu)\right]
$$
To compute the Fisher information, I would first have to find the log-likelihood function. Taking the natural logarithm, I get the following:
$$
\require{cancel}
\begin{aligned}
\log p(\mathbf x|\boldsymbol \theta) 
&= \log \Biggl( \frac{1}{\pi^d |\boldsymbol\Sigma|}\exp\left[-\frac{1}{2} (\mathbf x-\boldsymbol \mu)^{\mathrm H} \boldsymbol\Sigma^{-1} (\mathbf x-\boldsymbol \mu)\right]
\Biggr) \\
&= \log \Biggl(  \frac{1}{\pi^d |\boldsymbol\Sigma|} \Biggr) + 
\bcancel{\log} \Biggl( \bcancel{\exp} \left[-\frac{1}{2} (\mathbf x-\boldsymbol \mu)^{\mathrm H} \boldsymbol\Sigma^{-1} (\mathbf x-\boldsymbol \mu)\right]
  \Biggr) \\
&= \bcancel{\log 1} - \log \Bigl(\pi^d |\boldsymbol\Sigma| \Bigr) -\frac{1}{2} (\mathbf x-\boldsymbol \mu)^{\mathrm H} \boldsymbol\Sigma^{-1} (\mathbf x-\boldsymbol \mu) \\
&= -\log \left(\pi^d \right) -\log |\boldsymbol\Sigma|  -\frac{1}{2} (\mathbf x-\boldsymbol \mu)^{\mathrm H} \boldsymbol\Sigma^{-1} (\mathbf x-\boldsymbol \mu)
\end{aligned}
$$
The next step is to take the partial derivatives w.r.t the parameters to compute the Hessian matrix. When doing this, the first term is a constant so it would disappear. My questions concern the second and third terms.

What does it mean to take the derivative of the log of the determinant of the covariance matrix w.r.t a parameter? The source of my confusion is: I assume the data vector is a function of the parameters, and the covariance matrix obtained from the data, and the determinant would thus be a function of the parameters. By this reasoning, the derivative would be non-zero - yet, no representation of this shows up in the "standard" results for the Fisher information.
Similarly, when taking the derivative of the data vector $\mathbf x$ w.r.t a parameter, I would expect that since the data depends on the parameter, the derivative should be non-zero. But, I don't think this is the case.

The best reasoning I can come up with is: the data vector $\mathbf x$ represents a specific snapshot of the data and thus is not a function of the parameters per-se. Once the data has been obtained, it should be treated as a constant and therefore is independent of the parameters of the distribution. I don't know if this reasoning is sound.

How exactly do you conceive of the data as being functions of the parameters??  Data are numbers representing what you observe while parameters are hypothetical model constructs.  Maybe, before starting in on this problem, you should look at some simple textbook exercises.  Consider searching our site.

Thank you for the comment - I don't mean a function in the traditional sense, but that a change in the parameters would change the distribution of the data. I am taking the premise of the likelihood function as: given specific parameters, a specific set of data would have a certain likelihood of occurring. But as I think about this some more, I have it backwards - the likelihood function says given a snapshot of data, how likely is it that specific parameters produced that data.

A change in parameters would not affect the data one whit.  The data are what the data are; the parameters are part of a probability model you use to analyze the data.  Perhaps you will find our thread on likelihoods and probabilities illuminating.
